# Pi 4 able to run Kodi and Deluge at the same time?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, kodi, deluge

I'd like to run Kodi and Deluge at the same time on a Pi4.

Deluge to be an always-on torrent box, and Kodi for streaming TV/movies to my TV.

Will the Pi4 be able to handle both tasks at the same time?

Worst case scenario would be decoding 4k content while downloading torrents.

Thank you for any helpful advice :)

Comment: "*Worst case scenario would be decoding 4k content while downloading torrents.*", are you worry about system usage RAM/CPU?

Comment: Why do not try it?

Comment: I'm going to, but I'd like to know if it's likely that I'll have to buy two.

Comment: I am also hoping to draw on others experiences to see how they have gone in this scenario.  And what I should expect.

Comment: The devil will be in the details as usual. What will be the upload/download data rates? What local storage will you have? What codec your movies are encoded with? For one, with a slow HDD and a fast network you can bring any system to a stall by flooding the HDD with data.

Comment: Update.  It works :)